# How can I execute two methods at the same time to ensure there is no delay?

Tags: java, multithreading, simultaneous

I have a method `botMovement()` that controls USB robots. It is called twice with the parameter values/items from an `ArrayList` as followed:

```
for (BOTx1 aBot : theBotAL) { // theBotAL contains the BOTs DataType
    botMovement(aBot);
}
```

I would like both methods/functions to be executed simultaneously so that one bot (USB Robot) doesn't move before the other.

I understand that the for loop iterates element by element and so wouldn't be suitable for simultaneous execution, and so attempted the following:

```
botMovement(theBotAL.get(0)); botMovement(theBotAL.get(1));
```

However, although there is less of a delay, I understand that this too causes a slight delay.

Consequently, I'd like to know whether there is a way of calling both methods at the same times so the botMovement is synchronized.

Comment: Are you actually observing a delay?

Comment: @shmosel An extremely small one.

Comment: Each bot "could" be controlled by a seperate thread, BUT, there's still no guarantee that the methods would be called simultaneously, even with semaphores or targeted timed executions (so they would run after a specified time)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, Thanks. How could I go about controlling each bot using a separate thread?

Comment: @LearningToPython First, you need to define "how" you could stop each thread until you want them to run. Maybe start with [Concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: To your actual question: it is generally impossible to guarantee that synchronicity by conventional techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you are calling the botMovement from one thread(in case the botMovement doesnt create thread internally), so they are not running simultaneously but sequentially.

Best would be two create 2 threads that will wait for the latch, and when you call countDown() they would be notify to start.

```
      // CREAT COUNT DOWN LATCH
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

   //create two threads:
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
          try {
            //will wait until you call countDown
            latch.await();
           botMovement(theBotAL.get(0))

          } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
          try {
            //will wait until you call countDown
            latch.await();
           botMovement(theBotAL.get(1))
          } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        });

    //start the threads
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    //threads are waiting

    //decrease the count, and they will be notify to call the botMovement method
     latch.countDown();
```

Comment: Generally it is impossible to achieve what the OP asks with a guarantee, but this here is probably the best bet.

Comment: Great, thanks. So I'd have to create a new thread for every single bit?

Comment: This depend on your use case, if you don't have lot of moves than is ok to create new threads but if you have a lot of movement than  you should reuse the threads, but than you have to somehow send the tasks to the threads.